# Symfony form validate An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have for with fields type entity, drop down choice and required true but when submit form have error in console

```
An invalid form control with name='inbound_invoice_row[costObject]' is not focusable.
new:1 An invalid form control with  name='inbound_invoice_row[accountingAccount]' is not focusable.
new:1 An invalid form control with name='inbound_invoice_row[user]' is not focusable.
```

Another field validate fine, like vat or price but for accountingAccount user costObject have this error in console
why not understand

my form

```
    /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('location', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Location::class,
            'empty_value' => 'select_default_value',
            'query_builder' => self::getLocations(),
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'locations',
            'translation_domain' => 'invoicing'
        ])
        ->add('costObject', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => CostObject::class,
            'empty_value' => 'select_default_value',
            'choices' => self::getCostObjectHierarchy(),
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'cost_object',
            'translation_domain' => 'invoicing'
        ])
        ->add('accountingAccount', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => AccountingAccount::class,
            'empty_value' => 'select_default_value',
            'query_builder' => self::getAccountingAccount(),
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'accounting_account',
            'translation_domain' => 'invoicing'
        ])
        ->add('user', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => User::class,
            'empty_value' => 'select_default_value',
            'choices' => self::getR(),
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'employee',
            'translation_domain' => 'invoicing'
        ])
        ->add('description', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'description',
            'required' => false,
            'translation_domain' => 'invoicing'
        ])
        ->add('vat', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => $this->vatClasses,
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'vat',
            'translation_domain' => 'common'
        ])
        ->add('price', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'price',
            'required' => true,
            'translation_domain' => 'invoicing'
        ]);
}
/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'EconomyBundle\Entity\InboundInvoiceRow',
        'locations' => [],
        'employees' => [],
        'accounts' => [],
        'vat' => [],
        'cost' => [],
        'ajax' => true,
        'csrf_protection' => true
    ));
}
public function getName()
{
    return 'inbound_invoice_row';
}
```

create form in action

```
        $form = $this->createForm(
        $this->get('economy.form.type.in_bound_invoice_row'),
        $inboundInvoiceRow,
        [
            'validation_groups' => [InboundInvoiceRow::GROUP_POST],
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('inbound_invoices_row_create', ['id' => $inboundInvoice->getId()]),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ]
    );

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'save', 'translation_domain' => 'invoicing'));
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably have some js library that is used when rendering those fields (e.g. Select2 or Chosen). When there's some HTML validation error (e.g. the field is required but there is no value) on a field, but it's not visible - it might have `display` property set to `none` - then the browser is unable to attach error message to that field. This is what most likely triggers your error.

Simplest solution is to set `'required' => false` in form type options and rely on backend validation (e.g. using Symfony Validation component) rather than on basic HTML validation.